# What are these things in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

I have noticed two things about certain player's gamercards/tags in Destiny that I cannot figure out what they are/how to get them. Firstly, I often see people with gamercards/tags (I don't know the correct term) that have a message on them. At first I thought it was from your profile bio, but I added one to mine and it didn't show up. Secondly, when I look at the post-game carnage in the Crucible, I often see letters after some people's names, (usually all-caps). If anyone could explain these things to me that would be great.

EDIT: An example of the 1st question, the second place person has words that say "Warlock Master Race", however I have seen different things.

[image: An example of the 1st question, the second place person has words that say "Warlock Master Race", however I have seen different things.]

Comment: For the second part, it is their clan tag. For the first can you elaborate a little (or better, a screenshot)?

Comment: @TZHX I added a picture to show what I meant by the first question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your questions are the clan name/tag, the second place person is just in a clan that is named "Warlock Master Race."  On the carnage screen it only shows the clan tag, rather than the whole clan name.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the darker and more subtle text under the name of the player, then that is the clan tag. You join or create one on bungie.net. If you do, it also might take up to 24 hours to load up.

Comment: I just marked a flag of yours as unhelpful inicorrectly. My apologies